# Question regarding how to deploy windows form application with central database on client machine

Tags: c#, database, deployment, database-connection

I want to deploy a management system with central database as all users can access a single database also help me in writing connection string and how i make a server for central database.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

your question is not clear enough to get an accurate answer, but simply I can say you first need to add a connection string to your App.Config file like below and then use it in your code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourProjectName.My.MySettings.MyConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=yourUserName;Password=yourPassword"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and if you want to access db through internet you need to use IP instead of ServerName.
the connection string syntax is depends on what are you using as DB and many other things. to fine some template you can see https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Sample code:

```
    string connectionString;
    SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter db;
    string strsql1;
    SqlClient.SqlConnection con1;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    connectionString = My.Settings.MyConnectionString;
    strsql1 = "select * from tblUsers where UserName = '" + UN + "'";
    con1 = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con1.Open();
    db = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strsql1, con1);
    ds = new DataSet();
    db.Fill(ds, "tblUsers");
    ds.Dispose();
    db.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you @Ehsan Zand for that basically my issue is that i biuld a desktop application on C# i want to install it on client PCs (More than one PCs) installation of application is so simple but i want to make a server pc and want to connect all PCs with server PC where i put a single copy of my database and connect all of that with this database so that all user can manipulate with a singal database. Kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: That's the same, I know it's a little frustrating at first, but if you correctly define your connection string you can use your app through a network as you want without any other change. start to write your code then if you face any issue search and ask about that specific issue. I'm going to add sample code to my answer.